# Language Normalization with Lazy Loading in Ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, ngx-translate

I am about to implement Language Normalization with Lazy loading in my Ionic3 application. I am using the plugin `ngx-translate`. But I am getting the error `'TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined'`. Please help me to solve this error

### Code

### 1. app.module.ts

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

export function createTranslateLoader(https: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(https, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [Http]
      }
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    -------        
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.translate.addLangs(["en", "ml"]);
    this.defaultLng = this.translate.setDefaultLang("ml");
    this.translate.use(this.translate.getBrowserLang().match(/en|ml/) ? this.translate.getBrowserLang() : this.defaultLng);
}
```

### 3. login.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from './login';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginPage),
   TranslateModule.forChild()
  ],
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

### 4.login.html

```
 <ion-item no-lines>
    <span >{{'language'|translate}}:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span (click)="changeLanguage('en')">english</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span (click)="changeLanguage('sp')">Spanish</span>
  </ion-item>
```

### Edit

### Error , I am getting

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (vendor.js:55)
    at main.js:765
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:5291)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:5282)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (vendor.js:55)
    at main.js:765
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:5291)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:5282)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (vendor.js:55465)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (vendor.js:55458)
    at vendor.js:55505
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:5291)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Please check the below changes to the code posted in the question.

1. Import `MissingTranslationHandler` from `@ngx-translate/core`
2. Export a custom class called `MyMissingTranslationHandler` as shown below. And import it in `app.module.ts`

   `import {MissingTranslationHandler, MissingTranslationHandlerParams} from '@ngx-translate/core'`;

   `export class MyMissingTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
       handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
           console.log(params);
           return 'Translations not available for ' + params.key;
       }
   }`
3. `import { HttpClient,HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";`
4. `import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';`
5. Add the function `HttpLoaderFactory`

`export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
         return new TranslateHttpLoader(http,'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}`

6. In `import` array of the decorator `@NgModule` change the `TranslateModule` as

`TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })`

7. In the `providers` array add `{ provide: MissingTranslationHandler, useClass: MyMissingTranslationHandler}`

In our .module.ts file add `TranslateModule` in the `imports` array instead of `TranslateModule.forChild()` .

If you have any doubts, mention it in the comment section.

Comment: Yes `TranslateModule` without forChild is working in ionic3 ngx-translate and missingtranslationhandler

Comment: Yup, absolutely